# What's the difference between dev_addr and perm_addr of the struct net_device in linux kernel

Tags: linux-device-driver, ethernet

I'm reading the source code of the Linux(version 3.10)Ethernet drivers. There is one important structure *net_device* in the Kernel Netwoking.

Inside "*struct net_device*", there are two variables naming *dev_addr* and *perm_addr* indicating the mac address of NIC. However, some vendor driver set both of *dev_addr* and *perm_addr* while some set *dev_addr* only.

Though in the header file, it is commented as:

```
unsigned char       perm_addr[MAX_ADDR_LEN]; /* permanent hw address */
/* Interface address info used in eth_type_trans() */
unsigned char       *dev_addr;  /* hw address, (before bcast
                       because most packets are
                       unicast) */
```

Still I can't get the difference between them.

Thanks to skrrgwasme, also I found in the kernel file net/core/dev.c reigster_netdev() function that :

```
 /* If the device has permanent device address, driver should
 * set dev_addr and also addr_assign_type should be set to
 * NET_ADDR_PERM (default value).
 */
if (dev->addr_assign_type == NET_ADDR_PERM)
    memcpy(dev->perm_addr, dev->dev_addr, dev->addr_len);
```

So this variable is seldom used in NIC driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `perm_addr` field is populated if the device has a permanent MAC address assigned to it. This will usually come from some EEPROM or other read-only memory on the physical device.

The `dev_addr` field is the currently assigned MAC address, which can be changed by software.

Comment: Is there any concern that coping the memory content to dev_addr where is not pre-allocated?

    memcpy(dev->perm_addr, dev->dev_addr, dev->addr_len);

Comment: @craig Well, yeah. You should *always* check that pointers are pointing at valid memory locations before assigning to them. I don't know if this field is initialized when no `dev_addr` was present by default. I would check for null and malloc or kmalloc as necessary, then free the memory when the module is unloaded.